# Re-organize components when the screen-size changes

Tags: html, css, resize, css-float

When I have a navigationbar for example:

```
<div class ="navBar"> 
  <ul>​
      <li> ​        <a id=​"nav-questions" href=​"/​questions">​Questions​</a>​
      </li>​
      <li> ​        <a id=​"nav-questions" href=​"/​questions">​Answers​</a>​
      </li>​ 
  </ul> 
</div>
```

which will show on maximum screen-size something like this:

  ​
            ​        ​Questions​​
  ​
            ​        ​Answers​​
  ​

But when the screen-size is minimized to a size smaller than the navigation bar, it should stack vertical, like this:

- Questions
- Answers

I've read something about clearfix, but I'm not sure about it

Comment: You should read something about **Responsive Web Design**.

Comment: You can use media queries for that. Here have a look: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use media queries and the css would look something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:*insert nav width in pixels here*) {
    .navBar ul li {
        float: none;
        list-style-type: disc;
     }
}
 @media screen and (min-width:*insert nav width +1 in pixels here*) {
    .navBar ul li {
       float: left;
       list-style-type: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use css media queries to do it.

Comment: See this example http://jsfiddle.net/Ffv6d/. 

If you want a reponsive menu more elaboreted look my plugin Jquery on github https://github.com/gcajpa/responsive-menu.